# Converting c# code into python

Tags: c#, python, selenium

Hi I am using a selenium scraper and I coded it in C#, however I am required to convert it into Python for my application. I have difficulty in outputting the element into console window.

C# code

```
var elements = ghostDriver.FindElements(By.XPath("/html/body/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/ul/li[2]/ul/li/span[3]/span[3]"));

            foreach (IWebElement el in elements)
            {

                Console.WriteLine(el.Text);

            }

            Console.ReadKey(true);
```

Python code so far

```
print browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/ul/li[2]/ul/li/span[3]/span[3]').text
```

I get the error "unexpected token over the browser.find_element_by_xpath"
Any help would be appreciated,
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to encode the element_by_xpath to a utf-8 format

```
print browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/ul/li[2]/ul/li/span[3]/span[3]').text.encode("utf-8")
```

Answer (score 2):

You need the `find_elements_by_xpath()` (watch the `s`):

```
for element in browser.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/ul/li[2]/ul/li/span[3]/span[3]'):
     print(element.text)
```